# How can I change my display name, and avatar in Empathy?

Tags: 11.04, empathy, instant-messaging

How can I change both my display name, and avatar in Empathy Instant Messenger?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Navigate to **Edit > Personal
     Information**. *(if you're using Unity, the application menu is only visible if you hover the mouse cursor over the top panel.)*

[image]

- From here you may change the alias, or avatar of any account you wish. 
  *(your display name is known as an alias.)*

[image]

Comment: Ah, I simply did not realise that the "File, Edit, ..." menu is detached from the non-maximised window in Unity. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have changed in more recent versions of Unity and/or Empathy.  I was able to do this by selecting "Online Accounts" in the System Settings:

[image]

Clicking Options against my Empathy account:

[image]

Then editing the alias and avatar in the Online Accounts screen:

[image]